# LinqPad Scripts?

Tags: linq, linqpad

I've got a series of linqpad queries (c# programs) that I use to change values in a database. Currently, I need to open them all up one at a time, and run them manually.

I need to be able to just run the script, and have it execute all of the queries.

I have a folder structure something like this

```
A
    query1
    query2
B
    query3
    query4
C
    query5
    query6
```

What kind of script would I use to run this (bash, powershell, something inherent in Linqpad)?

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach

```
string htmlResult = Util.Run ("test.linq", QueryResultFormat.Html).AsString()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems linqpad has built in scripting support, using lprun on the command line. I was having trouble with this as you need to use lprun6 (I am using linqpad 6), instead.